# making string based on few conditions

Tags: python, string, list, function

I have a little problem with this task. I want to create a string with even number of chars. Amount of chars is taking from range (30, 100). For even position in this string chars are taken from char range (a, k) chars on odd position from char range (l, z). I tried to do it with list and convert this list to string using list comprehension, but I failed. What its wrong with this code and how can i change this into more elegant way(I mean using one line list compregension or something)

```
def get_text():
    def get_char_range(a1: str, b1: str):
        for c in range(ord(a1), ord(b1) + 1):
            yield c

    message = [] * random.randint(30, 100)
    for i, idx in enumerate(message):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            message.append(get_char_range('a', 'k'))
        else:
            message.append(get_char_range('l', 'z'))
    return message


def main() -> None:
    message = get_text()
    print(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[]

i tired using list comprehension, something like this

```
return [message.append(get_char_range('a', 'z') if idx % 2 == 0 else message.append(get_char_range('l', 'z')) for idx in message]
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `message.append(get_char_range('a', 'k'))`, what do you expect will be appended? Why? Where it says `message = [] * random.randint(30, 100)`, what do you think will be the resulting value for `message`? (Did you try to check? Were you right?) What will happen if you try to iterate over that?

Answer (score 0):

Note: it would help if there was a set of sample data to see if we understood the problem statement properly

Firstly, your result of `[]` was caused by this line:

```
[] * random.randint(30, 100)
```

Multiplying an empty list by a number returns an empty list, as there are no elements inside to multiply. Also note that if you want an even number for the length of the string, you can use `random.randrange(30, 101, 2)`. Note that the stop argument is exclusive.

Now let's solve the problem with your code. This should be a working version of your long code. It takes a random even length from [30, 100] and stores it in `str_len`.

It then goes through all the values in `range(str_len)`, and checks if it is even or odd. Based on the result, it calls `helper` (your function previous called `get_char_range`) with the corresponding parameters.

```py
def get_text():
    def helper(a1: str, b1: str):
        yield from (chr(c) for c in range(ord(a1), ord(b1)+1))

    message = []
    str_len = random.randrange(30, 101, 2)
    for idx in range(str_len):
        if idx % 2 == 0:
            message.append(helper('a', 'k'))
        else:
            message.append(helper('l', 'z'))
    return message


def main() -> None:
    message = get_text()
    print(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

We can make this shorter by realizing that since the string is even, it will simply alternate between the two sets of numbers `str_len/2` times.
This allows us to write:

```py
def get_text():
    return ''.join(([chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'), ord('k')+1)]+[chr(c) for c in range(ord('k'), ord('z')+1)])*(random.randrange(30, 101, 2)//2))
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_text())
```

This is a handful, so let's unpack it.

1. `[chr(c) for c in range(ord('a'), ord('k')+1)]+[chr(c) for c in range(ord('k'), ord('z')+1)]`

This adds two lists. The first list has all the numbers from `ord('a'), ord('k')` inclusive. The second list has all the numbers from `ord('l'), ord('z')` inclusive. Therefore, the resulting list will have all the numbers from `ord('a')` to `ord('z')`.

2. `*(random.randrange(30, 101, 2)//2)`

As mentioned previously, `random.randrange(30, 101, 2)` randomly chooses an even number from [30, 101). As we go through the list, we realize every other element will be even, and as such, the final answer will consist of the joined list from step one multiplied by the length of the string divided by 2 (The `//` is used to return an integer, as you cannot multiply a list by a float).

3.`''.join(fancy_stuff)`

This joins the list of numbers into one string.

Please note that the above solution gets a readability score of: 0/100. NEVER write this if someone else is going to be reading your code.

Let me know if this was what you wanted!